# convert images in html file to base64 using C#

Tags: c#, html, image, base64

I have an html file which I want to convert it's images from local source to base64 using C#.

```
<img width=83 height=100
  src="Untitled_files/image001.png" alt="cid:image003.png@01D3405F.B71FED30"
  v:shapes="Picture_x0020_1">
```

It'll be appreciated if you help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826390/how-to-convert-image-to-data-uri-for-html-with-c does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file's bytes and then convert it to base64:

```
byte[] imageArray =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"image path");
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

If the file is not local, you will need to [download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797485/how-to-download-image-from-url).

Comment: when I made base64 string, I should replace it with image path ?

Comment: How can I find images path in html file ?

Comment: @یـوسـفنـیـری This is a different issue than the one you ask in OP. Please ask another question.